# List Volumes with DF, Grep, Awk | Bash Shell

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep, linux-disk-free

Trying to print all entries which start with /Volumes/, this to list mounted volumes on mac. See Updates.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a volumes < <(
  df  | egrep -o '/Volumes/.*'
)

echo "${volumes}"
```

Update 1: This worked, but prints a space before each new line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a volumes < <(
  df | egrep -oi '(\s+/Volumes/\S+)'
)

printf "%s\n" "${volumes[@]}"
```

Update 2: Worked, but doesn't print volume names with spaces in it

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra volumes < <(
df | awk 'index($NF, "/Volumes/")==1 { print $NF }'
)

printf '%s\n' ${volumes[@]}
```

Update 3: Prints the second part of the volume name with spaces in it on a new line

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra volumes < <(
df | awk -F ' {2,}' 'index($NF, "/Volumes/")==1 { print $NF }'
)

printf '%s\n' ${volumes[@]}
```

**Solution:**

**Tested Platform:** macOS Catalina

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra volumes < <(
df | sed -En 's~.* (/Volumes/.+)$~\1~p'
)

printf '%s\n' "${volumes[@]}"
```

**DF Output**

```
Filesystem    512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity iused       ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5   976490576   21517232  529729936     4%  484332  4881968548    0%   /
devfs                781        781          0   100%    1352           0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s1   976490576  413251888  529729936    44%  576448  4881876432    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s4   976490576   10487872  529729936     2%       6  4882452874    0%   /private/var/vm
map auto_home          0          0          0   100%       0           0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
/dev/disk7s1       40880       5760      35120    15%     186  4294967093    0%   /private/tmp/tnt12079/mount
/dev/disk8s1       21448       1560      19888     8%       7  4294967272    0%   /Volumes/usb drive
/dev/disk6s1  9766926680 8646662552 1119135456    89%   18530 48834614870    0%   /Volumes/root
/dev/disk2s1    60425344   26823168   33602176    45%  419112      525034   44%   /Volumes/KINGS TON
```

Comment: (1) Your `read` creates an _array_ variable with one input line in each element. `${volumes}` expands to the first element (subscript 0) only; use `${volumes[@]}` or possibly `${volumes[*]}` (2) Each line/element in the array _should_ be a matching string, and I don't know why it isn't. Look manually at just `df | egrep -o ...` and see if that is correct.

Comment: try `df | egrep -o '(^/Volumes/\S+)'` or `df | egrep -o '(\s+/Volumes/\S+)'` depending on which column you want (use -i for case insensitive)

Comment: please see update, white space problem

Comment: It did not print any space on my end. Try my solution.

Comment: this works with spaces in filenames `df | egrep -oi '(\s+/Volumes/.*)' | egrep -o '(/.*)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this pipeline in `OSX`:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra volumes < <(
df | sed -En 's~.* (/Volumes/.+)$~\1~p'
)
```

Check array content:

```
printf '%s\n' "${volumes[@]}"
```

or

```
declare -p volumes
```

```
declare -a volumes=([0]="/Volumes/Recovery" [1]="/Volumes/Preboot")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @anubhava , when di do 
echo  ${volumes[@]} , it prints all the volumes on one line?

Comment: thank you, it worked , only problem is it won't list volumes with a space in the name.

Comment: btw your grep command also uses `\s+/Volumes/\S+` which won't find volumes with spaces.

Comment: yes I know, it is a problem for people who uses spaces in their volumes, I don't, but some do.

Comment: it produces the same output.  as the previous edit.

Comment: No it is not. I am getting correct output. Check this demo: https://ideone.com/SnLgJg

Comment: what i see is that you use brackets  '[%s]\n', which prints it correctly, but with brackets around it... opposed to POSIX format

Comment: output -> [/Volumes/KINGS TON]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211338/discussion-between-anubhava-and-adrian).

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a volumes < <(
  df -h | awk 'NR>1 && $6 ~ /^\/Volumes\//{print $6}'
)
printf "%s\n" "${volumes[@]}"
```

The `awk` command gets all lines other than the first one (`NR>1`) and where Field 6 ("Mounted on") starts with `/Volumes/` (see `$6 ~ /^\/Volumes\/`), and then prints the Field 6 value.

The `printf "%s\n" "${volumes[@]}"` command will print all the items in the `volumes` array on separate lines.

If the volume paths happen to contain spaces, you may check if there is a digit followed with `%` followed with whitespaces and `/Volume/` and then get join the fields starting with Field 6 with a space:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1 && $0 ~ /[0-9]%[ \t]+\/Volumes\//{for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) {a=a" "$i}; print a}'
```

Comment: thank you - it worked. But when i renamed (with spaces in it) one volume it only picked up the first word in it (King) and not (King ston)?

Comment: @Adrian  What did you rename it to? Do not use spaces. I never use spaces in Linux in file and folder names.

Comment: i never use it either, just want it to work in case someone does use spaces

Comment: @Adrian Then use `df -h | awk 'NR>1 && $0 ~ /[0-9]%[ \t]+\/Volumes\//{for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) {a=a" "$i}; print a}'`

Comment: @Adrian I added the solution for spaces, too

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear just what output you want, but you can always use `awk` to parse the information. For example if you want the "Filesytem" and "Mounted on" information, you can use with `df`:

```
df | awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^\/Volumes/) {
            print $1, substr($0, match($0,/\/Volumes/))
            break
        }
    }'
```

Or using the input you provided in the file `dfout`, you could read the file as:

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^\/Volumes/) {
            print $1, substr($0, print $1, substr($0, match($0,/\/Volumes/)))
            break
        }
}' dfout
```

**Example Output**

Using the file `dfout` with your data you would receive:

```
/dev/disk8s1 /Volumes/usb drive
/dev/disk6s1 /Volumes/root
/dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/KINGS TON
```

If you need more or less of each record, you can just output whatever other fields you like in the `print` statement.

Let me know if you want the format or output different and I'm happy to help further. I don't have a Mac to test on, but the functions uses are standard `awk` and not GNU `awk` specific.